# Ruby on rails Devise Send Mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, devise, gmail

I've been following this tutorial on how to setup Devise. I'm able to make a new User&Email and hit submit. It says "User succesfully created" and in the server log I can see the email that was just sent with subject, email adress to user, name of user etc and it says "Completed 302 Found in 434ms". I don't know what the problem is though because I don't receive an email, although the user gets saved to the database. I'm using gmail to send email.

This is the server log (Changed email addresses to --- for privacy):

---

Sent mail to ------@-------.com (389ms)

Date: Fri, 12 Aug 2011 09:11:45 -0500

From: ------@-----.com

To: -------@-------.com

Message-ID: <4e4534a175b12_b3e----6b6f998510d8@ubuntu.mail>

Subject: Registered

Mime-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: text/plain;

charset=UTF-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Thank you for registering!

Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/4

Completed 302 Found in 434ms

---

Anyone know how it could be solved or recognize the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked your config/environment/development.rb file?  Make sure that config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries is set to true.  See below:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true 
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail #:smtp
```

Otherwise, it's likely actually being sent and your email account is dropping the message silently.  Turn up the first option above (…raise_delivery_errors = true) to see.

Comment: Note, your last line likely says :smtp instead.  If you're on Mac or Linux, I would use :sendmail as it's much better/faster while you're in development.